# Register new OS X file type by extension & associate with Cocoa app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, package, plist

OK, so here's the deal :

- I've got a new app which I want to associate with a new file type - let's say `.xyz`
- `.xyz` files - if that matters at all - is a **Package** file.

Now, here's how the filetype-specific portion of my `info.plist` looks like :

```
CFBundleDocumentTypes = (
        {   
            CFBundleTypeExtensions = ( "xyz" );
            CFBundleTypeIconFile = "xyz-icon";
            CFBundleTypeName = "XYZ file";
            CFBundleTypeRole = "Viewer";
            LSTypeIsPackage = "1";
        }
    );
```

However, the `.xyz` package files are still shown as folders and NOT as a single file ("package"). What am I doing wrong?

---

***HINT :** I've managed to do that in the past, but I simply cannot remember if I'm missing something. Perhaps the system has to be restarted? I have no idea...*

Comment: What type are you actually using? Have you verified that you don't have any other applications that can handle the .xyz type on your system that might be declaring it without `LSTypeIsPackage`?

Comment: @PeterHosey Yep, I'm 100% sure. It's a unique 7-letter extension used only by my app.

Answer (score 7):

If you found this stackoverflow page because `LSTypeIsPackage` isn't working for you, it might be because you're using `LSItemContentTypes` to declare your document type. The use of `LSItemContentTypes` makes the system ignore `LSTypeIsPackage` (which isn't the case in this stackoverflow question).

If you're using `LSItemContentTypes`, you need to make your exported type conform to `com.apple.package`. Example:

```
CFBundleDocumentTypes
  LSItemContentTypes
    Item 0 = com.example.xyz
  CFBundleTypeExtensions
    Item 0 = xyz
  CFBundleTypeRole = Editor
  etc.

UTExportedTypeDeclarations
  Item 0
    UTTypeIdentifier = com.example.xyz
    UTTypeConformsTo
      Item 0 = public.data // or whatever
      Item 1 = com.apple.package          <-------------
    UTTypeDescription = XYZ Document
    etc.
```

Comment: Setting `UTTypeConformsTo` is necessary if `LSItemContentTypes` is used.

Answer (score 2):

You need to export your type.

```
UTExportedTypeDeclarations = (
  {
    UTTypeDescription = "Your File Type Description";
    UTTypeIconFile = "xyz-icon";
    UTTypeIdentifier = "your.uti.xyz"
    UTTypeTagSpecification = {
      public.filename-extension = ("xyz")
    }
  }
```

Disclaimer: I'm used to the XML plist syntax, so there might be a syntax error in the above, but it should be basically the correct structure.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to set the "package bit" also known as the "bundle bit" to signal to the OS that this folder is a package.

Comment: Walt, thanks! It seems like I posted the correct code here in SO, but I had missed the `LSTypeIsPackage = "1";` bit in my original `info.plist`. Funny... lol

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary if the “folder” bears one of the filename extensions given in the document type dictionary, and the same type dictionary has the `LSTypeIsPackage` key set to true.

Comment: @PeterHosey I get your point. However, adding the LSTypeIsPackage *did* fix it. So...

Comment: @Dr.Kameleon: That's what I would have expected. That isn't what Walt Sellers suggested, though, and his answer is what I was saying shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

If you install your app I believe your exported types (from your Info.plist) will let the system know about your packages.

While it's in development, you might want to set the "package bit" Walt mentioned, with something like:

```
    if !directoryURL.setResourceValue(true, forKey: NSURLIsPackageKey, error: &error) {
        println("Soft warning: cannot set package bit for \(directoryURL)")
    }
```

Because I don't think the Finder will look in your development directory to find new universal types.

Comment: the "Finder" looks Everywhere for UTIs, even in trash. It's not the finder which does this it is actually a service called LaunchServices

Comment: Yes. I’ve seen lots of situations in which LaunchServices doesn’t correctly update its cache in a timely manner—it’s not deterministic in my experience, so I don’t rely on it.